# #VBA - Run time error - 2147352567 (80020009) : cannot Parse Condition,. Error at "("

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I am trying to fetch the email detail which contains 14000 emails. I need to put some filter like sender name is Merrill and dates should be previous month.

I did write a code for the same but getting cannot parse the condition.

```
Sub Create_Report()
    Dim ol as outlook.application
    Dim ns as outlook.namespace
    dim fol as outlook.folder
    Dim I as object
    dim mi as outlook.mailitem
    Dim filterstring as string
    dim n as long
    
    set ol =new outlook.application
    set ns = ol.getnamespace("MAPI")
    set fol = ns.folders("Audit").folders("inbox")
    Filterstring = "@sql=(""urn:schemas:httpmail:frommail""='Merrill' AND %lastmonth(""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"")%)"
    
    For each I in fol.items.restrict(filterstring)
         If I.class = olmail Then
             set mi = I
             debug.print mi.subject, mi.size
        End If
    Next I
    set ol = nothing
    set ns = nothing
    set fol = nothing
    set mi = nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: After `For Each` statement, the `if` statement, did you close it by `endif` or `End If`: Is it a typo while writing the question or you did this in the vba code?

Comment: it is "end if"... It was a typo while writing the question. I am sorry, I do not understand what should I alter in for each statement.

Comment: Before `for each` in filterstring, did you forget the quotes in the end, like it's in the question?

Comment: The code was typed manually. It was not copied and pasted. So It looks that I missed typing that. Code corrected.

Comment: Put breakpoints into the code, what line, where exactly you get the error?

Comment: Also, add watches in the variables and see while debugging, for example, if any object is getting 'Nothing' instead of the object or getting an expected value (more info about debugging check it out: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code). Then put the results here (you can edit the question also or here in the comments), and the line which triggers the error

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply.... the code is working now... the only problem i could figure out was putting "@SQL" has to be in capital letters and my code had it in small letters.  Now it is picking out the email from last month (June 2020) but it is also fetching 3 emails from 31st May. Any idea about it.

Comment: I'm not an expert in Outlook, it's strange because your query asked only for e-mails from lastmonth... Maybe these 3 emails from 31st may are in some way connect with another from June (e.g belonging to same conversation with some email from last month)?